# How to turn off a notification coming from a website?

Tags: linux-mint, notifications

I accidentally subscribed to news notifications from a stock market site and now I am getting notifications every few minutes that are irritating me.

I do get other notifications for email I'd like to keep. How can I find which alerts are active on my system and turn them off? Or failing that, turn them all off.

I am working on a Linux Mint 17.3 system, it is my own (I have the root password).

P.S. The Zacks.com site has an alert area, but it says I am not subscribed. I thought this was the site, but the alerts don't show who they are from, and I was surfing other market sites yesterday, too. So I'd just like to know how to look at a list, or if getting rid of cookies would work, or something like that.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but is it impossible to unsubscribe from zacks.com?

Comment: Usually there is an unsubscribe link in newsletters.  If there is none, put the sender on a blacklist.  How to do that will depend on your mail-provider.  In the worst case you need to configure your mailclient accordingly.

Comment: Are your talking about Web Push notifications in Firefox or in another browser? If so what browser are using?

Comment: @markgraf Perhaps I am using the wrong terminology, these aren't emails, they are pop-ups in the corner of my screen that last for about 2 seconds. There is no corresponding email to go with it.

Comment: @Gounou yes, I am using Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable Web push notifications for a site in Firefox :

Click on the "i" (left of the green lock on the address bar).

Open permissions preferences.

Notifications/Settings

Block the website

Comment: Wow. I had to navigate to Zacks, but then I tried that, it did say I had notifications enabled with an "X" to disable them. I did.  If I go half an hour without them, I'll accept your answer. Thanks very much!